# VSCode - multiline selection - deselecting a line

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I have these lines:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
key4 value4
```

I click just before `key` hold CTRL + ALT and press arrow down few times. Now my cursor is at the beginning of both lines:

```
|key1 value1
|key2 value2
|key3 value3
|key4 value4
```

Is there a keyboard-only way to deselect a particular line? I thought it could be CTRL+ALT+SHIFT and then arrow up but that changes the selection based on the inital cursor (basically selects key1 line and any line above if it exists.

What I want to achieve is to be able to go back to:

```
|key1 value1
|key2 value2
|key3 value3
key4 value4
```

But only using keyboard. Sometimes when selecting, I select one extra line - with a mouse it's sometimes a lot of clicking to get to the right position.

Comment: you can click a particular cursor to deselect it

Comment: with extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-remove-cursor) you can remove the last or first cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will undo the last cursor operation.

```
|key1 value1
|key2 value2
|key3 value3
|key4 value4
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

```
|key1 value1
|key2 value2
|key3 value3
key4 value4
```

The only way to arbitrarily remove cursors is by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L-Click</kbd> on the location of the cursor you would like to remove.